# Embedding of Cuntz algebras $O_2\subseteq O_3$?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

The Cuntz algebra $O_n$ is the (universal) C*-algebra generated by n-isometries $s_1,...,s_n$ such that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n s_is_i^\ast =\mathbf{1}, \ \hbox{and}\  s_i^\ast s_j=\delta_{ij} \mathbf{1}\ (\hbox{for all}\ i,j).$$

For example if $s_1, s_2$ are the generators of $O_2$ then $s_1^2, s_1s_2, s_2$ generate a copy of $O_3$ in $O_2$ (as they satisfy the relations of $O_3$) as pointed out by Cuntz in page 184 in [Comm. Math. Phys. 57(1977), 173-185](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103901288).

Now i wonder if one can generate a copy of $O_2$ in $O_3$ by manipulating the generators of $O_3$?

Comment: Do you want a unital embedding?

Comment: Yes please, although $O_2$ sitting inside $O_3$ with a possible different identities.

Comment: You can always do that as you pointed out in your comment to Darth Vader's answer. You can't send the identity of $O_2$ to the identity of $O_3$ for K-theoretic reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. According to Lemma 2.1 in  (K. Kawamura, Universal algebra of sectors, Int. J. Alg. Comput. 19(3)(2009), 347–371.) we have:

$Hom(O_m, O_n)$ is nonempty if and only if $m=(n-1)k+1$ for some $k \geq 1$.

Applying this to the case for $Hom(O_2, O_3)$ gives that we must have $2=2k+1$, which is impossible.

Comment: On the other hand, Prop. 4.2.3, page 75, in the textbook "Classification of Nuclear C*-algebras (Encyclopedia of Mathematical Sciences Vol 126)" says that $O_2$ embeds unitally in $pAp$, where $p$ is any (full) properly infinite projection in a given C*-algebra $A$ with $[p]_0=0$ in the K-group $K_0(A)$. 

So Kawamura result implies that there is no C*-alg $A$ and proj $p$ such that $pAp=O_3$?

Comment: In any properly infinite, unital $C^\ast$-algebra $A$, you can find a full, properly infinite projection $p\in A$ with $[p]_0 = 0$ in $K_0(A)$ (this is due to Cuntz, see also Prop. 4.1.4 in Rørdams classification book). In particular, $\mathcal O_2$ embeds unitally into $pAp \subseteq A$. Such a $C^\ast$-algebra $A$ contains a unital embedding of $\mathcal O_2$ if and only if $[1_A]_0 = 0$ in $K_0(A)$.